# Is Dale Gribble just in denial that his "son" is not his, or is he actually clueless?

Tags: plot-explanation, king-of-the-hill

In *King of the Hill*, is Dale Gribble just in denial that his "son" is not his, or is he actually clueless? I have seen many episodes but I can't figure out which it is.

Answer (score 5):

Dale knows that he is not Joseph's biological father.

He doesn't know that John Redcorn is the father. Dale thinks the father is aliens.

Despite this knowledge, he has accepted Joseph as his own.

[Of Mice and Little Green Men](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0764027/)

*When Dale realizes that he did not have sex with Nancy anywhere near the time Joseph was conceived, he becomes convinced that a space alien is his son's real father.*

Comment: Your second linked clip shows that Dale actually believes that aliens stole his sperm to create Joseph, so he does believe he’s the biological father.